# How to add some javascript code on top of my grid to work in back-office

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am working with Umbraco 7.5 grid and I've created some macros that work with javascript. I need a javascript array on the page on top of my grid so I can add my items to it.

```
<script>
  if (!_components) _components = [];
</script>
```

I can do it on the normal view since I have access to master page. but how can I do it in the back office?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier to maintain if you will create separated, custom grid property editor for your control / macro. Then you'll be able to add anything you want in the output of the editor and it will be included only when the specific control will be used in backoffice.

Check documentation here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/grid-layout/build-your-own-editor

You can also check **LeBlender** package - https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/leblender/. I've used it to play with the Grid a couple of times. It's giving you a visual UI to create and manage those custom editors with params and anything you need there.